# Generic Object Name to access datasource connection manager MBean in Liberty

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere, websphere-liberty, mbeans

I am trying to access DataSource ConnectionManager MBean using java client.I am able to access it when I specify the datasource name and JNDI name in Object Name.I need a generic approach which can be applicabe for any datasource in server.xml, since this is done as part of a framework that can be used in any application.

I tried multiple options but all the time I got 'javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException'.

Sample code is as given below:

```
<library id="oracle-lib">
 <fileset dir="lib" includes="ojdbc6.jar"/>
</library>

<dataSource jndiName="jdbc/db" id="oracleDB" type="javax.sql.DataSource">
  <jdbcDriver javax.sql.DataSource="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource" libraryRef="oracle-lib" />
  <connectionManager agedTimeout="10" maxIdleTime="1800" connectionTimeout="180"  minPoolSize="10" maxPoolSize="1" reapTime="180"/>
  <properties.oracle user="user" password="password"
            url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//db-server:1521/db"/>
</dataSource>
```

Object name that worked:

```
ObjectName jvmQuery = new ObjectName("WebSphere:type=com.ibm.ws.jca.cm.mbean.ConnectionManagerMBean,jndiName=jdbc/db,name=dataSource[oracleDB]/ConnectionManager[default-0]")
```

Generic Object Names I tried:

```
1.WebSphere:type=com.ibm.ws.jca.cm.mbean.ConnectionManagerMBean,*
2.WebSphere:type=com.ibm.ws.jca.cm.mbean.ConnectionManagerMBean,name=dataSource[default-0]/ConnectionManager[default-0],*
3.WebSphere:service=com.ibm.ws.jca.cm.mbean.ConnectionManagerMBean,*
4.WebSphere:service=com.ibm.ws.jca.cm.mbean.ConnectionManagerMBean,name=dataSource[default-0]/ConnectionManager[default-0],*
5.WebSphere:service=com.ibm.ws.jca.cm.mbean.ConnectionManagerMBean,name=dataSource[default-0]/ConnectionManager[default-0]
```

Could you please advise..

Thank you,
Biju

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query option #1 should work fine:

```
WebSphere:type=com.ibm.ws.jca.cm.mbean.ConnectionManagerMBean,*
```

I just tested it with several data sources in my configuration and got the following:

```
Found MBean: WebSphere:type=com.ibm.ws.jca.cm.mbean.ConnectionManagerMBean,jndiName=jdbc/ds1,name=dataSource[ds1]/connectionManager
Found MBean: WebSphere:type=com.ibm.ws.jca.cm.mbean.ConnectionManagerMBean,jndiName=jdbc/ds2,name=dataSource[ds2]/connectionManager
Found MBean: WebSphere:type=com.ibm.ws.jca.cm.mbean.ConnectionManagerMBean,jndiName=jdbc/ds3,name=dataSource[ds3]/connectionManager[default-0]
Found MBean: WebSphere:type=com.ibm.ws.jca.cm.mbean.ConnectionManagerMBean,jndiName=jdbc/XAds,name=dataSource[XAds]/connectionManager
```

Keep in mind that Connection Manager MBeans are lazily created.  If you are expecting to find an mbean in a query, make sure that you have gotten a connection from the data source before. Getting a connection from the data source will force a Connection Manager (and its MBean) to be created.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.. I am also able to find MBean when I mention JNDI name and dataSource name in Query. Here I am looking for a common query for all MBeans. Without mentioning any specific datasource or jndi name. For example: for the four datasources you tested, a single query should  work for all of them.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to query for all mbeans of a type without knowing jndi name, as I have shown above. If that is not working, open jconsole and ensure the mbeans are actually there.

Comment: I am still confused. I get  'javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException : WebSphere:type=com.ibm.ws.jca.cm.mbean.ConnectionManagerMBean,*'. I could see the MBeans in JConsole.

Comment: update your question with a code example of how you are attempting to query for the MBean. JConsole uses the same API you are using and it is able to find the MBeans, so perhaps there is an issue with how you are querying beyond the ObjectName string

Comment: I got it working..!! I think I made a mistake by doing `mbeanServer.getMBeanInfo(jvmQuery);` . I removed this line and its working. Thank you so much Andy.